# Closing tag won't respond

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, components

I'm building a news web app in react and closing tag won't respond as when splitting components, what can be done?... I have tried restarting vs code and still encounter the same problem.

Comment: Can you provide a code example or a print screen of the error?

Comment: Thank you Ary, it's finally responding after restarting my computer